# Python runs code whenever I hit enter....just started doing this

Tags: python

I just starting learning Pyhton.  In my first class we wrote some super-basic code in Idle.  I tried to play around with a homework problem and noticed that after I type a line of code, I hit enter, and then code executes.  So 1) I can't write more than 1 line of code 2) this just started...I didn't do it last time I opened the program.

For example, last week I was able to type all this in, and then hit F5 for it to execute.  Now I can't type more than one line and F5 doesn't do anything and the RUN option isn't in the menu bar anymore. WHAT am I doing wrong?

## Program to give area of right triangle based on base and height.

base_number = input("What is your base size? ")
print
height_number = input("What is your height size? ")
print
area_number = base_number * height_number / 2.0
print str(area_number) + " right triangle area"

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a Python **Shell** within Idle, not the Idle **IDE**.

If you double click on .py's to open the association is wrong. If not, you're clicking the wrong shortcut / start menu item / EXE.